# android studio profile no debug app (ram test)

Tags: android, testing, ram

Im QA analyst.

Before me there is a task, to find out how much RAM the application consumes. The application is downloaded from Play Market. In the profiler, I do not see this process (no debuggable processes). Is there a way to profile a third-party application?
[screen adnroid studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGQwN.jpg)

What I have tried:

- adb shell dumpsys meminfo "com. XXX."

Yes, it shows the RAM consumed by the application, but each time to enter this command is not convenient. I would like to see on the chart. Or to write to the log every second.

- Third-party application with Play Market, show only the general memory of the device.

Or can you recommend another method or application? I really hope for help!

Comment: You may need a rooted device, or set `ro.debuggable=1`.

Comment: create a script that will run `adb shell dumpsys meminfo "com. XXX."` every second, and store the values to a file, from which you can build the graph

Comment: @GenoChen, thanks for the answer! Suppose I have a rooted device, what should I do next? What is "ro.debuggable = 1" and where to write it?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko, Hello! I do not know programming languages at all =( What can I do about it and how difficult is it?

Comment: You can either learn them, or pay someone for such a script. Basically you want a tool, which will simplify your work.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko, I do not exclude such a variant of events. But I hope that you can do in another way. In any case, thanks for the advice!

Comment: @ДмитрийРоманов As far as I know, you will see those processes when `ro.debuggable=1`. You can google for how to write it (rebuild kernel images, use memory hack, etc.), if you have a rooted device.